# Conditional WHERE statements based on parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to conditionally create a `WHERE` clause in a stored procedure.  It is to act as a filter on a boolean column and there's only two outcomes I want - either only take the true values, or take all of them (no situation where I only need the false values).

The clause I am trying to use is this -

```
WHERE 
(@customerInactive = -1 OR `listcustomers`.`active` = 1)
```

with the idea either the parameter is a -1 (no filter) or we do have a filter and should do listcustomers.active = 1.

I tried being more explicit as well

```
WHERE
((@customerInactive = 1 AND `listcustomers`.`active` = 1) OR 
(@customerInactive <> 1 AND 1=1))
```

The second one ends up not returning anything then.  How can I fix this?

This is in a stored procedure, using MySQL 5.6.

Edit:  Given that I've been told my first query should do it, but it always returns `listcustomers`.`active` = 1, is this possibly a type issue?  I made customerInactive a int(11).  I also just tried it as a bit(1) but I am still getting the same issue, no matter my paraemter I get the TRUE filter.  Or in the case of the second query, no results.

Edit 2:  I don't think this should matter but the final result is the union of multiple tables of which I am going to have to do this same sort of filtering.  The whole SQL query can be seen here - https://pastebin.com/6wL4ZtnF

Comment: Your first query should do what you want.

Comment: If `@customerInactive` is true, you want only the `listcustomers.active = 0`, otherwise you want all of them?

Comment: Using the first query for some reason ALWAYS returns the TRUE filter even if I pass in the -1 as a parameter.

Comment: @Cid Correct.  Right now I have `@customerInactive` as an int and have been using 1 to indicate I want the true filter, otherwise I want them all.

Comment: `customerInactive` is a user variable or a stored procedure parameter?. Try [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2tQaqodZqWXLoJmioViud/0).

Comment: @wchiquito Thanks, I saw something there that helped me solve it.  I was using an @ in front of the parameter when taking that away and just using `customerInactive` worked.  I guess I was inconsistent with using @ to declare the parameter and then using @ to reference it, so the @customerInactive = 0 always failed and I always got listcustomers.active = 1.   Thanks

Comment: Check [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) and [13.1.15 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments, this is the results you want depending of customerInactive and the value of listcustomers.active

```
@customerInactive | listcustomers.active | result
------------------+----------------------+--------
 0                | 0                    | 1
 0                | 1                    | 1
 1                | 0                    | 1
 1                | 1                    | 0
```

This is a NAND (Not And) that can be written such way in SQL :

```
NOT (@customerInactive = 1 AND listcustomers.active = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that I confused parameters and user defined variables.  I am passing in customerInactive as a parameter to the stored procedure, so I should reference it directly by name.  Using the `@` made it look like a User defined variable which was NOT defined, hence the constant failing of my initial equality and why the true filter was always on.  Thanks everyone.